# javascript wait return function into onclick

Tags: javascript, callback, wait, dhtmlx

We have this code (using DHTMLX and DHTMLXMESSAGE):

```
myCheckBox.attachEvent('onEditCell', function(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue){
        dhtmlx.confirm({
            type:"confirm",
            text: "Are you sure?",
            callback: function(result){
                if(result) {
                    return true;
                } 
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

OnEditCell event should return "true" or "false" to validate action.

Now my code always check my checkbox and then show the confirm popup.

Comment: I did not understand the question itself. Can you pls be little clear?

Comment: I've changed the question with a similar clear example.

Comment: Sorry, but whats the meaning of "I need to wait this function that returns true or false"? ARe you waiting for someother event by any chance?

Comment: Before there was a function (named changeGroups() ) that performs some operations and return a boolean value. But my question is different, How can I link the return value into confirm callback function to attachEvent callback? (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Did it work? I was waiting for your reply. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return anything to attachEvent callback. Based on the result of your confirm checkbox, execute the relevant code

```
> callback: function(result){
>                 if(result) {
>                    //don't returnfrom here
                      // execute your code here only.
>                 } 
>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make JavaScript block on asynchronous functions.

Have your event handler always return false.

Then trigger its functionality inside the callback instead of trying to return true.

Comment: Please, can you provide me an example?

Comment: `dhtmlx.confirm( yada yada ); return false` and `callback: function(result){ if (result) { whatever_returning_false_prevents(); }`